# QML images are not loaded, but everything works in the QT Designer

Tags: image, qt, qml

I have a problem.
Set: QT Creator 9.01 and QT 6.4
I'm creating an empty project Quick QT Application
I use the Build System - Cmake

The project has only a Window with dimensions and an image as a background.
Here is my Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6


Window {
    width: 375
    height: 812
    visible: true
    color: "#28333f"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "images/background.svg"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }
}
```

When I launch the application I get an error
**QML Image: Unable to open: qrc:/background.svg**

But at the same time, if I open this project in designer mode, I see that the image is inserted correctly, it is present and there are no errors.
Here is a screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtmQJ.png)

After Googling and reading the forums, I created a res resource file.qrc to which I added the prefix / and add image file.
In the code, I change the path to the image file to this:
**source: "/images/background.svg"**
^^

And then when I start the project, everything works correctly for me and an image appears.
But another problem arises.
If you switch to Designer mode. All images disappear

How to win it ?

Comment: you probably have to use `qrc:` scheme if you load your image from resource file. now it looks that you load that from the file system.

Comment: no
, by default  qrc scheme is used when I work in the Designer. That's also why I created the resource file.

Comment: Did you reconfigure the project after changing the resource file? Anyway, in QtCreator, left click on the image file inside *.qrc, you will see `Copy URL...` and paste that to the `Image.source`. You have to see the image in all the modes. If this is not the case you probably do something wrong (qrc path, an image file path, cmake config ...) Please provide [mcve] so we can run and test it.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to put image from a resource in the Qt Designer. It looks that designer doesn't respect the resource file at all. It just rewrite the path without scheme and path. The problem that it works in the Designer only, and vice versa - a correct path works in the application but not in the Designer. Looks like a bug.